# HAZUS 3.0 for ArcGIS 10.3.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, hazus

I have not downloaded HAZUS 3.0 yet and am currently using ArcGIS 10.3.1 on my machine. I would like to know if HAZUS 3.0 runs on ArcGIS 10.3.1 or if not any alternatives?

Comment: I recently found out that FEMA is working on a release that should work for all versions in ArcGIS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Hazus Help Desk Resource and Solutions Page](http://www.fema.gov/hazus-help-desk-resource-and-solutions-page), a question asking for compatibility is mentioned in the FAQ section:

---

**Q. What versions of ArcGIS is Hazus-MH 3.0 compatible with?**

*A. Hazus-MH 3.0 is compatible with ArcGIS 10.2.2.*

---

There is no mention of ArcGIS 10.3.1.